# Creating a Login UI with Firebase but it goes to Main Activity

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to make a Login UI using Firebase. I created a user and tested to log into the app. Now that I did that, every time I start the app, instead of going to the LoginActivity (My MAIN Activity already set on Android Manifest) it starts at the MainAcitivty (once the Login is successful it should redirect to that). My code is this:

```
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;

private String email;
private String password;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    final TextView emailEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailField);
    final TextView passwordEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordField);
    Button loginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginButton);
    Button registerButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.registerButton);

// Getting the firebase reference url

final DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();


    loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // Retrieves user inputs
            email = emailEditText.getText().toString();
            password = passwordEditText.getText().toString();

            // trims the input
            email = email.trim();
            password = password.trim();
            // When a user signs in to your app, pass the user's email address and password to signInWithEmailAndPassword
            mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(LoginActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            Log.d("TAG", "signInWithEmail:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                            // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                            // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                Log.w("TAG", "signInWithEmail", task.getException());
                                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });

        }
    });
    // responds to changes in the user's sign-in state
    mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (user != null) {
                // User is signed in
                Log.d("TAG", "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());

                // Authenticated successfully with authData
                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);

            } else {
                // User is signed out
                Log.d("TAG", "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
            }
        }
    };
    registerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class));
        }
    });
}
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (mAuthListener != null) {
        mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
    }
}
```

Android Manifest

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="false"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".LoginActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".RegisterActivity"></activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a user is authenticated via Firebase, their credentials are stored locally. You need to explicitly log the user out each time if you want to always start at your LoginActivity.

Use `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();` in your `onStop()` of your MainActivity to force a user to be logged out when the app is closed.

The documentation here has more info: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/custom-auth

Comment: Thanks. I put it like this

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mAuthListener != null) {
            mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
        }
    }

And added it on a button on MainAcitivty to log users our